# Retrofit response needed on onBackPressed

Tags: android, retrofit

I have made some asyncronous retrofit calls with success. 
But now I have a problem, I need the data of the retrofit call available on my onBackPressed method, with my other calls I run my code on the onResponse method of the retrofit call, but now how can I do it....
I need the data before the user presses backbutton, also I do not like do it syncronously as it may lock the app....
For your information, the data needed is a config data which tells the app to show or not a toast on pressing back button.
Which is the right way to do it?

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        callGetConfigApi().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseConfig>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseConfig> call, Response<ResponseConfig> response) {
                List<Config> results = fetchResults(response);

        config_string = results.getStringText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseCategory> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                showErrorView(t);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, config_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

is this correct? what if user press before data is ready?

Comment: You might be showing some loading progress while making API calls.
so during progress, the view will be blocked,

or you can set default behaviour for toast, incase like API failure or before API success

Answer (score 1):

You got two options:
1) Show a Progress/Loading dialog and make `setCancelable(false)` on that, which will disable back button functionality until the dialog is visible/showing
2) Overide the `onBackPressed` which as i can see you allready did in your code, just display a usefull message to make user understand the need to stay at the screen before leaving or navigating to other screen, as long as you aren't calling `super.onBackPressed()` user wont be able to go back to previous activity. (Exceptional case 'user hits the HOME or RECENTS BUTTON')

Answer (score 1):

Making API calls is an asynchronous operation, it takes time and more importantly it works on the background thread. When you press the back button, the user generally wants to go back, but making API calls will have two disadvantages, either you will have to make the user wait for the call response, and then for the appropriate message, it will never be a smooth experience, and will cause a bad UI/UX, secondly, you cannot start another activity in between the API call, the API call will never complete because when an activity is removed from the stack `onDestroy()` is called and it is destroyed and you may also be getting an error.

I would suggest making the API call and fetching the data in the `onStart()` method. After that when the user presses the back button, you do not have make the API call, you can access the already fetched data and do whatever you want.

If somehow the user presses back before the data is ready, you might be getting a `NullPointerException` in toast. you can just check for that before displaying